# Casting back on generic types

Tags: c#, generics, casting

Assume the following example. A generic approach to database connection handling.
`DbConnection.BeginTransaction()` (from System.Data.Common) returns a `DbTransaction` instance.
Since this is explicitly stated, why do I need to explicitly cast it?

```
internal abstract class ADatabase<DbCommandType, DbConnectionType, DbTransactionType> : IDisposable
    where DbCommandType : DbCommand, new()
    where DbConnectionType : DbConnection, new()
    where DbTransactionType : DbTransaction, new()
{
    DbConnectionType _connection;
    DbTransactionType _transaction;

    void Foo()
    {
        _transaction = _connection.BeginTransaction(); // <-- Error..
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is

> Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Common.DbTransaction' to 'DbTransactionType'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Of course I can cast it, but the question is **why**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your generic has a constraint that says that `DbTransactionType` needs to be the class `DbTransaction` **or any class derived from it**.

With that highlight, it should be clear that you shouldn't even explicitly cast it.

But if it is not clear:
The return value of `BeginTransaction` is an instance of type `DbTransaction`. The type of `_transaction` is `DbTransactionType` which could be a **sub-class** of `DbTransaction`. You can't assign a variable of a base class to a variable of a sub-class without casting. And the cast will only work if the variable of the base class actually contains an instance of that sub-class.

When thinking about this problem, in your mental model replace `DbTransactionType` with `string` and `DbTransaction` with `object`. Now the problem should become clear immediately.

Comment: @odyodyodys: Please read my answer again. It is the same as if you are asking why you have to cast an `object` when you want to assign it to `string`.

Comment: The `public abstract class DbConnection.BeginTransaction()` returns a `DbTransaction` and not an `object`. Please correct me if got this wrong.

Comment: @odyodyodys: Oh boy. Really? Sorry to say that, but you have to read more carefully. Anyway, I updated my answer.

Comment: Got it thanks! Both answers (till now) say the same. I am marking this one as correct because of the details.

Answer (score 3):

You just restrict `DbTransactionType` to `DbTransaction` *or any subclass* as long as the type has a parameterless constructor. So, while you can use any subclass in place of `DbTransaction` the same is not true in the other direction and `DbTransactionType` could refer to such a subclass, making the assignment of a `DbTransaction` problematic.